# Evento click javascript não chama a action - Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Eu criei um bloco modal para exibir minha View Create. Ao clicar no btnNovo, um evento javascript deve chamar a minha Action Create retornar uma view em branco e carregar dentro da modal... Só que apenas a modal está abrindo. Eu acompanhei com BP e constatei que o evento do click não está chamando a Action Create com a rota que eu estou passando. Alguém sabe me dizer onde estou errando?

```js
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWritePessoaSituacaoData")]
        [Route("situacoes-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo")]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Segue abaixo o código do btnNovo, o bloco modal e a ref. ao script:

```js
 <a id="btnNovo" class="btn btn-outline btn-default new" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"
                   data-original-title="Cadastrar Novo" >
                    <span title="Cadastrar Novo" class="icon wb-plus"></span> Cadastrar Novo
                </a>
```

```js
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Gerenciar Situações de Pessoas</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modal-content">
                    Carregando...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
@section scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    
    <script src="~/js/PessoaSituacao/PessoaSituacao.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    }
```

Segue o script js:

```js
$("btnNovo").click(function (eve) {
    $("#modal-content").load("situacoes-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo");
});
```

Comment: Qual é o nome da controller e a rota para ela? o caminho no load está incompleto
`$("#modal-content").load("/{controller}/situacoes-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo");`

Comment: Controller PessoaSituacao  Action Create.

Comment: Você tentou?
`$("#modal-content").load("/PesssoaSituacao/situacoes-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo");` ?

Comment: Eu havia tentado, mas acho que eu estava errando ao passar uma rota errada... Agora sim, funcionou!!! Obrigado Leandro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no seu apontamento no evento de click do botão

```
$("btnNovo").click(function (eve) {
    $("#modal-content").load("situacoes-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo");
});
```

Aqui você está indicando apenas a rota da sua action partindo da rota atual
que inclui a action atual. Como informado nos comentários a sua `Controller` se chama `PessoaSituacaoController` e não possui uma customização de rota para a mesma, logo por default seria `PessoaSituacao`. Levando esses apontamentos em consideração, para resolver o seu problema basta indicar a url para o carregamento da modal respeitando o padrão `/{Controller}/{Action ou Rota}/`, que no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$("btnNovo").click(function (eve) {
    $("#modal-content").load("/pessoaSituacao/situacoes-gerenciamento/cadastrar-novo");
});
```